# Q: Landau Vol. 3, Section 103 (3rd ed.) Quantization of the rotation of a top

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, coordinate-systems, rigid-body-dynamics

Have been reading section 103 of L&L quantum mechanics, and have some problems with understanding/interpretation. Hope someone can help out.

In the section it is said that the coordinate system $\xi$, $\eta$, $\zeta$ points along the principal axes of inertia of a top (solid body), and rotates with the object. I'm having trouble interpreting $\hat{J}_\xi, \hat{J}_\eta, \hat{J}_\zeta$. I do not quite follow the explanation of why the angular momentum components in the rotating frame commute differently than components in a non-rotating frame. Could someone provide a clearer explanation, or a reference where this is shown in more detail?

In subsection *The Symmetrical Top* it is said that not only $\hat{\boldsymbol{J}}^2$ and $\hat{J_z}$ commute (where $z$ is an axis of the non-rotating frame), but that $\hat{J}_\zeta$ also commutes with them. How can one show this by direct calculation (as the text suggests)?

Finally, a conceptual question. In the end of *The Symmetrical Top* the wavefunctions are deduced. How can they be functions of $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$? These are the Euler angles regarding the orientation of the solid body, which vary in time as the body rotates. Shouldn't the wavefunctions be functions of the spherical angles $\theta,\phi$ in the non-rotating frame? Also, if  there's a quick explanation why these functions have to be normalized according to $\int |\psi_{JMk}|^2 \sin \beta d\alpha d\beta d\gamma=1$, it would be greatly appreciated.

Below I list some relevant information from the text.

The section starts by stating that the Hamiltonian can be written
$$ \hat{H}=\frac{1}{2}\hbar^2 \left(  \frac{\hat{J}_\xi^2}{I_A} + \frac{\hat{J}_\eta^2}{I_B} + \frac{\hat{J}_\zeta^2}{I_C}  \right), $$
where the $I$'s are the principal moments of inertia. Even here I don't quite see the correct interpretation. Do these ang. momenta have to be considered to exist in a non-rotating frame that has its axes along the principle axes of inertia at some instant in time? If yes, I don't see why the commutation is different, since these momenta just refer to some right-hand coordinate system. Or are the $\hat{J}_\xi, \hat{J}_\eta, \hat{J}_\zeta$ really operators with respect to the moving frame (not stationary which coincides with the object at some instant)? In this interpretation however, the object is stationary by definition (perhaps not including the spin, but I'm not sure), and I fail to see how the Hamiltonian above gives the correct value of energy.

Anyway, let me give more information regarding the definitions of $\hat{J}_\xi, \hat{J}_\eta, \hat{J}_\zeta$. At some point in the text it is mentioned that $\hat{J}_\zeta = \hat{\boldsymbol{J}}\cdot \boldsymbol{n}$, where $\boldsymbol{n}$ is a unit vector pointing in the direction of the $\zeta$ axis. Also in problem 1 at the end of the section it is mentioned that ang. momentum operator along any axis is given by $-i\partial/\partial\phi$, where $\phi$ is the angle of rotation about this axis.

Comment: Coule you define the operators $J_\xi$, etc, for those who don't have the Landau with them all the time?

Comment: @Adam, I have added some info. I don't see any way to share the pages themselves, so summarised to the best of my ability.